# Create Expression<Action> from Method name with overloaded constructor

Tags: c#, autofac, expression-trees, hangfire

I am using Hangfire and have a method to schedule jobs by assembly,type and method name. Using the default constructor works properly but all the methods have overloaded constructors that will be activated using Autofac.

```
//Works for a default constructor
Type type = Type.GetType("typestring, assemblystring");
var method = type.GetMethod("methodstring");
Expression[] args = new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(options,typeof(Options)) }; //All methods use the same parameters
var action = Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Call(Expression.New(type), method, args));
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(action, "cronstring");
```

Trying to modify to support overloaded constructors (No default) I have this code.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("typestring, assemblystring");
var method = type.GetMethod("methodstring");
Expression[] args = new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(options,typeof(Options)) }; //All methods use the same parameters
var ctor = type.GetConstructors().ToList().FirstOrDefault();
var ctorParams = ctor.GetParameters();
var ctorArgs = new Expression[ctorParams.Length];
for (int i = 0; i != ctorParams.Length; ++i)
{
   ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), ctorParams[i].Name);
   ctorArgs[i] = Expression.Convert(param, ctorParams[i].ParameterType);
}            
var ctorExpress = Expression.New(ctor, ctorArgs);
var action = Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Call(ctorExpress, method, args));
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(action, "cronstring");
```

I receive this error: InvalidOperationException: variable '{first constructor param}' of type 'System.Object' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I am not sure if I am missing something or am going the wrong way about this. I have limited experience using expressions.

Comment: Seems like, you are trying to call the constructor if it would have an `object[]` as a single parameter. If you goal  is to use that kind of constructor, then you should fix constructor search part. At the most end somehow the parameters should be passed into the constructor, either within `RecurringJob` or with constants, if you can define those and pass at the moment of definition

Comment: It is suppose to be `object` instead of `object[]`, thank you for noticing that. The constructors can have N parameters and I am trying to fill them with object casted to the param type. The `Expression<Action>` is stored in a DB and executed by another program and DI will fill the constructor. `Expression.Call()` requires an instance expression for non-static methods.

Comment: DI will not call the constructor as it is called in the `Expression` already

Comment: You're making `ParameterExpression` objects. You're rightfully passing them to `Call`, but you have neglected passing them to `Lambda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken and there is another code that would compile your expression and calls it, providing as a parameters `object[]`, and you have to put those parameters into constructor sequentially, then you can use sample code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type type = typeof(Foo);
    var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) });
    var ctorParams = ctor.GetParameters();
    var dynPar = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "d");
    var ctorArgs = new Expression[ctorParams.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i != ctorParams.Length; ++i)
    {
        var indVal = Expression.ArrayIndex(dynPar, Expression.Constant(i));
        ctorArgs[i] = Expression.Convert(indVal, ctorParams[i].ParameterType);
    }
    //{ new Foo(Convert(d[0], Int32), Convert(d[1], String))}
    var ctorExpress = Expression.New(ctor, ctorArgs);
    //{ new Foo(Convert(d[0], Int32), Convert(d[1], String)).Run()}
    var callRun = Expression.Call(ctorExpress, type.GetMethod("Run"));
    //{ d => new Foo(Convert(d[0], Int32), Convert(d[1], String)).Run()}
    var action = Expression.Lambda<Action<object[]>>(callRun, dynPar);
    action.Compile()(new object[] { 1, "a" });
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int a, string b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
    public int A { get; }
    public string B { get; }
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"It is {A} and {B}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ASpirin, your input helped resolve this issue. I changed the constructor's arguments to `Constant` instead of `Parameter` and passed in `null`.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("typestring, assemblystring");
var method = type.GetMethod("methodstring");
Expression[] args = new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(options,typeof(Options)) }; //All methods use the same parameters
var ctor = type.GetConstructors().ToList().FirstOrDefault();
var ctorParams = ctor.GetParameters();
var ctorArgs = new Expression[ctorParams.Length];
for (int i = 0; i != ctorParams.Length; ++i)
{
   var param = Expression.Constant(null,typeof(object)); //Updated this line
   ctorArgs[i] = Expression.Convert(param, ctorParams[i].ParameterType);
}            
var ctorExpress = Expression.New(ctor, ctorArgs);
var action = Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Call(ctorExpress, method, args));
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(action, "cronstring");
```

This is able to work since Hangfire doesn't actually execute the constructor and saved the expression like this:

```
//Class name is Test, method name is Run
var test = Activate<Test>();
test.Run(FromJson<Options>("REMOVED"));
```

`Activate<Test>` is activated using Autofac in the another program.